# Top bar sees tag wiki edit suggestion, but I cannot actually review it

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing

[image: In the header, the "1" number appears. The browser is opened on Review | Suggested Edits page which shows that "There are no items for you to review".]

As you can see on screenshot above, top bar informs me about one tag wiki edit suggestion, but because I don't have enough points, I cannot review it. After clicking the link, I get to the page showing that there are no items for me to review. If there are no items for me to review, why bother me with the information on top bar?

Comment: You have enough reputation: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits . The number in the corner shows up for me when "There are no items for you to review" when I just finished reviewing the suggested edits. I have never had a misleading flag-thing (what is that called?).